# The height of the textarea in my core-input isn't matching the height of the core-input itself

Tags: css, polymer, dart-polymer, core-elements

The `textarea` (red) that's inside this `core-input` (blue) Polymer element isn't scaling to the height of the `core-input` element itself. I think it used to work, and so maybe this is due to changes in core-elements (I'm using the latest released)? Or is it some styling I've done?

(Live is at http://mycommunity.org – sign up, go to a community, click Add Stuff.)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You are talking about the height alone right, not the width? Please mention that in your question

Answer (score 1):

The rows attribute specifies the visible height of a text area, in lines. Note: The size of a textarea can also be specified by the CSS height and width properties.

So either specify a `height` or how many `rows` it should have.

Comment: Removing `rows` from both the core-input and textarea doesn't help. Might have something to do w/ the fact that this is a more complex (Polymer) custom element than a simple textarea.

Answer (score 1):

Using the CSS properties found [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html) just add the attribute 'fit' to the text area:

```
<textarea fit id="input" rows="fit" placeholder="Sharing is caring..." maxlength="" aria-label="Sharing is caring..." aria-invalid="true" on-change="{{ inputChangeAction }}" on-focus="{{ inputFocusAction }}" on-blur="{{ inputBlurAction }}" required=""></textarea>
```

Or as Claudiu said, assign `core-input` a height.

#### **EDIT: If you change the position of the `core-input` to `absolute` then it'll work, though it might push the boundaries of your dialogue box, but nothing some quick CSS can't fix.**

Comment: The problem with `fit` is the `textarea` is generated by the `core-input` and thus not cleanly accessible to me. The problem with assigning a set `height` to `core-input` (which works) is that I want the `core-input` to be as tall as the remainder of the dialog hence `height:100%`.

Comment: Well then. Simply changing from `height:100%` to `height:1px` on the `core-input` seems to have done the trick, on Chrome at least for now. Why?

Comment: The width and height properties don't actually function the same way. If we have a blank HTML page with a 'div' (height and width 100%), only the width would assume the full space of the 'body'. To get the height property working in a similar way, we must explicitly state the height of the 'body' as 100%. Not quite sure why it's like this. Setting your height to 1px has a similar effect in this case where the 'min-height' overrides the 1px height property. This ultimately means it wouldn't (in theory) dynamically change size, so it's stuck at 117px min-height.